# Display image inside DevExpress MVC GridView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I'm trying to display small image inside devexpress grid. 
My controller return an image file to my view which is fine(please do not advise me to store image path in my db instead file itself, this is not the question here) to continue I'm getting image in my view calling

```
Url.Action("GetImage", "Property", new {id = image.Id })
```

Thats working fine except in devexpress gridview.

If anyone have expirience with `DevExpressHelper.WriteToResponse()` and know how to use it to properly render `<img  width="50" height="50" src="/Property/GetImage/5" alt="">` inside devexpress gridview please share.

Thanks

Comment: would you share more your GridView's definition and clarify where do you want to display image?

Answer (score 1):

The DevExpressHelper.WriteToResponse method seems to be obsolete.

I believe you can use the approach suggested in the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q313518 DX KB as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The grid supports templates. One template type is for styles.

Have a look at this demo: 
http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/GridView/Templates

For ASP.NET WebForms you could look here
http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Templates/Template.aspx

**Edit:** Provided WebForms demo, when a MVC demo would have appropriate

Comment: The MVC grid demos are at http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/GridView/Templates, I'm updating my answer